# How to mock an async function inside useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I might be missing something in here, I'm trying to mock an API function inside of my useEffect hook.
The API call should return a version number (i.e 1.0.0) 
I tried to mock and sent it to the component, but for some reason, it's not working.

My useEffect hook:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        async function loader() {
            const ver = await loadVersion();
            if (ver === 401) {
                history.push("/login");
                return;
            }
            setVersion(ver);
        };
        loader();
    }, []);
```

My test:

```
describe("Footer", () => {
  const loader = jest.fn();
  const loadVersion = jest.fn(() => '2.0.0');
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Footer loader={loader} loadVersion={loadVersion}/>)
  })
    it("Renders without crashing", () => {
      expect.assertions(1)
      expect(wrapper).not.toBeNull();
      wrapper.update();
      console.log(wrapper.debug()) // I'm trying to get the version from mocked loadVersion.
    })
})
```

I tried to debug it to check if it is getting to mocked function but it's not, and in my coverage report it is not passing the first line of the async function inside the useEffect hook.

Comment: I think any updates for hooks need to have wrapped with `act`..so maybe the process of mounting  needs to be wrapped with `act`..https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act

Comment: @AnirudhMangalvedhekar I tried that as well, still the same =\

Comment: Maybe `useEffect` is not being called as the component is rendered using `shallow`?

Comment: @AlbertAlises I tried with mount as well, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: hello. did you manage to solve this? I tried to follow up with the course I am doing, by setting ```resetMocks```: false on package.json, with no success as well